# How to identify Matrix is singular to working precision in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using MATLAB to do compute conditional covariance and mean using Gaussian mixture model, which always relates to [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). It is suggested in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) that if the matrix `C` is singular, generalized inverse of `C` can be used to compute the Schur complement.

In MATLAB, `pinv` is for this aim. As my matrix is very large (more than 1000 columns) and will result in covariance matrix with size `> 1000*1000`, it can be much faster to use `eig` instead of `svd` to compute the `pinv`. However, this can lose remarkable precision as it truncates eigenvectors corresponding to small eigenvalues under set threshold.

Another way is to use `rmdivide` function to compute `BC^(-1)` as `B/C` since the inverse of a matrix can be considered as a least square problem. In my problem, this can obtain much higher precision and run much faster than using `B*pinv(C)`. Further, `rmdivide` can deal with some singular matrix, therefore, this method is preferable. But in some cases the warning `Matrix is singular to working precision` can arise, which result in `NaNs` if `rmdivide` is used. So, is there a way to identify when this warning will arise, thus I can use `pinv` instead?

**Update**

Additional to @Dohyun's answer, what I'm now doing is to check the obtained results, basing on the fact that `NaN` can be obtained in the results if the matrix is singular.

```
warning('off','MATLAB:singularMatrix')
x = b/C; % in my codes, vector is obtained, I think matrix can also be checked in this way
if isnan(sum(x))
    x = b*pinv(C);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your matrix `C` is 'usually' nonsingular and `mrdvide` is much faster than `pinv`, then you can try `mrdivide` and then catch warning to switch to `pinv`.

However, in MATLAB, we cannot catch the warning by using `try`. Fortunately, there is [undocumented solution](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently) to catch the warning.

The basic idea is turn `warning` to `error` for specific warning ID (in your case, `MATLAB:singularMatrix`) you will have, and then use `try` and `catch`.

```
myWarn = warning('error','MATLAB:singularMatrix'); % turn singular matrix warning to error
try
    u = mrdivide(B,C);
catch
    u = B*pinv(C);
end
warning(myWarn); % return to warning
```

Comment: +1! slight improvement: it's better to use `ws = warning('error', ...)` and then at the end, `warning(ws);`. That way, the warning state is reset to whatever it was before the operation, rather than forcing it `'on'`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. But I do not prefer `try ... catch ...` pattern as this can significantly slower the computation if it is inserted into loops with large number iterations. I have updated my own solution for my question. I think it is more straight forward.